# Disable `PaperTrail.enabled` globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, paper-trail-gem

I'm using Puma as my web server, and have in `application.rb`:

```
config.after_initialize do
  #run `spring stop` before change takes effect.
  PaperTrail.enabled = false
  # do this again just to be sure I've set it
  PaperTrail.paper_trail_store[:paper_trail_enabled] = false
end
```

I'm able to login to `rails c` and see: `PaperTrail.enabled?  #=> false`

However, when I'm posting a request to one of my endpoint with `binding.pry`, and when I do `PaperTrail.enabled? #=> true`. I've created an app from scratch and it's running webrick and still has the same issue. How do I properly disable paper_trail everywhere?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/635

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable PaperTrail globally like this.

create file. config/initializers/paper_trail.rb

```
PaperTrail.config.enabled = true
PaperTrail.config.has_paper_trail_defaults = {
  on: %i[] # notice that, there is no items in array, meaning not triggered in any situation.
}
```